# Bootstrap break in column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to have a Website with 4 columns using Bootstrap.
My problem now is: inside the columns the text does not break (just one line, into the next col).

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-3">
      <h4>First</h4>
      asdasd asda sd asd asdhbsc sbdsdbsad dchbdf hcds cd
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Second</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Third</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Fourth</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I handle the breakpoints in the cols (I don't want to give them fixed widths)?

Comment: According to bootstrap , it will automatically breaks the when it reaches the col width

Answer (score 2):

Go to getbootstrap.com and learn more about bootstrap columns .

Bootstarp is 12 column grid layout .so there is no class called col-xs-18  in bootstrap .

Here col-xs-* is for mobile device.. Better use all four classes like below

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <h4>First</h4>
      asdasd asda sd asd asdhbsc sbdsdbsad dchbdf hcds cd
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <h4>Second</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <h4>Third</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <h4>Fourth</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can write like   `<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">` . If you have same column for all device then you can just write it for small one. Suppose you need  four columns for extra small and small device and two column for medium and large device then you can write like `<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6">`. @Adarsh Gowda K R

Answer (score 0):

rewrite col-xs-18 to col-xs-3

http://jsfiddle.net/apr7c4Lq/

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <h4>First</h4>
      asdasd asda sd asd asdhbsc sbdsdbsad dchbdf hcds cd
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Second</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Third</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">
      <h4>Fourth</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: col-xs-18 is only for responsive... it was a problem in my CSS... Thank You

Comment: so you  can use another class for responsive, use both col-xs-18 and col-xs-3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has 12 columns. So you can't write like  `<div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-3">` . If you need four columns, you can write it like `<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3">`. 
xs= extra small device, xm= small device, md= medium device, lg = large device. Suppose, you need four columns for all device then you can write `<div class="col-xs-3">`.